# Start method just once for addition / removal of association elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, after-save, after-create

I have a `Composition` model which has a `has_and_belongs_to_many :authors`.

I need to fire a method after a composition changed its authors, although, since it involves the creation of a PDF file (with the name of the authors), I want to call this method only once, regardless of the number of authors added / removed.

Of course I can add / remove existing authors from the composition, so a `before_save` / `after_save` won't work here (somehow it recognizes new authors added to the composition, but not existing ones).

So I tried using `after_add` / `after_remove`, but the callbacks specified here will be invoked for every author item added to / removed from the composition.

Is there a way to have a method called only once for every "batch action" of adding / removing items from this kind of relationship?

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for a `service` rather than a `callback`.

Comment: @jvillian can you suggest an example of how to write such a service?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what a service *might* look like:

```
class UpdateCompositionAuthorsService

  attr_accessor *%w(
    args
  ).freeze

  class << self 

    def call(args={})
      new(args).call
    end

  end # Class Methods

  #======================================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #======================================================================================

    def initialize(args={})
      @args = args
      assign_args
    end

    def call
      do_stuff_to_update_authors
      generate_the_pdf
    end

  private

    def do_stuff_to_update_authors
      # do your 'batch' stuff here
    end

    def generate_the_pdf
      # do your one-time logic here
    end

    def assign_args
      args.each do |k,v| 
        class_eval do 
          attr_accessor k
        end
        send("#{k}=",v)
      end
    end

end
```

You would call it something like:

```
UpdateCompositionAuthorsService.call(composition: @composition, authors: @authors)
```

I got sick of remembering what args to send to my service classes, so I created a module called `ActsAs::CallingServices`. When included in a `class` that wants to call services, the module provides a method called `call_service` that lets me do something like:

```
class FooClass
  include ActsAs::CallingServices

  def bar
    call_service UpdateCompositionAuthorsService
  end

end
```

Then, in the service class, I include some additional class-level data, like this:

```
class UpdateCompositionAuthorsService

  SERVICE_DETAILS = [
    :composition,
    :authors
  ].freeze

    ...

    def call
      do_stuff_to_update_authors
      generate_the_pdf
    end

    ...

end
```

The calling class (`FooClass`, in this case) uses `UpdateCompositionAuthorsService::SERVICE_DETAILS` to build the appropriate arguments hash (detail omitted).

I also have a method called `good_to_go?` (detail omitted) that is included in my service classes, so my call method typically looks like:

```
class UpdateCompositionAuthorsService

    ...

    def call
      raise unless good_to_go?
      do_stuff_to_update_authors
      generate_the_pdf
    end

    ...

end
```

So, if the argument set is bad, I know right away instead of bumping into a `nil` error somewhere in the middle of my service.